# Laravel Auth::attempt() and Auth::check() fail

Tags: authentication, laravel-4

I am following this tutorial line by line: http://scotch.io/tutorials/simple-and-easy-laravel-login-authentication

I pass authentication, no problem. But, when I refresh the page, and use `Auth::check()` it returns false, and I am not logged in! How do I login? I tried adding `Auth::login(Auth::user(), true)` and that didn't help either!

Comment: Do you have anything that might block cookies in your browser? Could you try a different browser?

Comment: Cookie is enabled, and this also doesn't work on Firefox/Chrome/Safari

Comment: Are you getting any error there??

Comment: Guys, Auth::check() is failed. I did Auth::attempt(). But, It return false. Why? Please advice.